# Does double projection preserve lines?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ and $ W $ be two subspaces of Euclidean space $ \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $ \dim{V}=\dim{W}, x\in V $. Is it true, that $ \mathrm{Pr}_V(\mathrm{Pr}_W(x)) = c \cdot x $ for some $ c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} $, if $ c $ depends on $ \langle x\rangle $? (where $ \mathrm{Pr}_X $ denotes orthogonal projection on subspace $ X $).

I think it's true in case of equal dimensions, but my attempt to use definition and scalar product failed.

Comment: What does this mean: "if $ c $ depends on $ \langle x\rangle $"? If you don't ask the question correctly, you might not get correct answers.

Comment: I meant that $ c $ depends on $ x $. I wrote $ \langle x \rangle $, because it's obvious that if such constant exists, then it's the same for all vectors of the form $ kx $, where $ k\in\mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider the two linear subspaces $V=\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ and $W=\{0\}\times \mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ both of dimension 1 and note that they are orthogonal subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This yields that $\text{Pr}_V(w)=0$, for any $w\in W$. Therefore $\text{Pr}_V(\text{Pr}_W(x))=0$ as $\text{Pr}_W(x)\in W$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and hence $c=0$.

Answer (score 2):

[Martin’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154864/265466) provides a simple counterexample with orthogonal subspaces, for which $\Pr_VPr_W=0$, i.e., not only elements of $V$, but every vector in $\mathbb R^2$ is mapped to zero. Here’s a counterexample in which the composition of the two projections is nontrivial: Let $V=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0)^T, (0,1,0)^T\}$ and $W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,1)^T,(1,0,-1)^T\}$. The second coordinate of the image of any vector under $\Pr_W$ is zero, and $\Pr_V$ simply sets the last coordinate to zero, so if the second coordinate of $x$ is nonzero, then there is no scalar $c\ne0$ such that $\Pr_V\Pr_Wx=cx$.

Comment: Actually, I probably shouldn't exclude case $ c=0 $. (or I should wrote that $ V \cap W^\perp = 0 $)  That's exactly the case I'm interested.